# Recipe files included in a cookbook are not getting picked up when running Chef Client

Tags: ruby, jenkins, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe

In a cookbook, `default.rb` is the file which will be picked/executed. I added **service.rb** in the same folder `cookbooks/cookbook_main/recipes` folder, in which default.rb resides. I then uploaded the cookbook and executed the chef-client on a remote VM which acts as a node.

Logs showed that it detected both the rb files under recipes folder. Here is the problem, Script present in default.rb was executed but not the one in service.rb. Why?

PS: (New to Chef, so please correct if am wrong !)

Comment: What is your run_list set to? Is this running through Vagrant? It would also help to have your run output.

Comment: run_list has only one cookbook named 'cookbook_main'. Vagrant does the booting up of VM and runs the Chef Client the first time. Output just doesn't show the rpm's I am trying to install from service.rb, while it shows everything present in default.rb.

Comment: Does the order of existence (default.rb and then service.rb or vice versa inside recipes folder)  matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have `cookbook_main` in your run_list like so:

```
chef.add_recipe "cookbook_main"
```

When you only have the cookbook specified in your run list without specifying a recipe, Chef will only run the default recipe. For example, these two lines are essentially equivalent:

```
chef.add_recipe "cookbook_main"
chef.add_recipe "cookbook_main::default"
```

If you want to run the new service recipe you need to tell Chef to run it. There are a couple of ways to do this. One is to explicitly add it to your run list in your Vagrantfile:

```
chef.add_recipe "cookbook_main"
chef.add_recipe "cookbook_main::service"
```

Otherwise you can include it via your default recipe. So add this line somewhere in your default.rb recipe:

```
include_recipe 'cookbook_main::service'
```

Comment: I would recommend starting with the official [Learn Chef](https://learn.chef.io) website. I haven't read any books on Chef so I can't really recommend any.